# ListView row selection gets cut off around Icon when using VCL styles

Tags: listview, delphi, png, vcl, vcl-styles

I use the following code to draw icons on a ListView subitem from a PNG ImageList in the "CustomDrawSubItem" event. When I select a row or change the row's brush color from "CustomDrawItem", this selection color gets cut from the subitem's cell. How can I fix this so the "background" color fills the transparent area?

[image]

DPR file

```
program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.Styles;

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Glow');
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Unit1

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
   Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
   Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, System.ImageList, Vcl.ImgList,
   Vcl.ComCtrls, Winapi.CommCtrl, PngImageList;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    PngImageList1: TPngImageList;
    procedure ListView1CustomDrawSubItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem; SubItem: Integer; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure DrawPicOnListViewSubItem(LV: TListView; Item: TListItem; SubItem: LongInt; ImgListHandle: THandle; IconIndex,ImgListWidth: Word); inline;
Var R: TRect;
    x: LongInt;
begin
  R := Item.DisplayRect(drBounds);

  for x := 0 To SubItem - 1 Do
   R.Left := R.Left + LV.Columns[x].Width;

  R.Top := R.Top + 3;
  If Item <> nil then begin
    R.Left  := R.Left + (LV.Columns[SubItem].Width - ImgListWidth) div 2;
    R.Right := R.Left + ImgListWidth;
    // Ensure that the items are drawn transparently
    SetBkMode(LV.Canvas.Handle, TRANSPARENT);
    ListView_SetTextBkColor(LV.Handle, CLR_NONE);
    ListView_SetBKColor(LV.Handle, CLR_NONE);
    ImageList_Draw(ImgListHandle, IconIndex, LV.Canvas.Handle, R.Left - 2, R.Top, ILD_NORMAL);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1CustomDrawSubItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem; SubItem: Integer; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  if SubItem = 1 then begin
    DrawPicOnListViewSubItem(ListView1, Item, SubItem, PngImageList1.Handle, 0, 16);
    DefaultDraw := False;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Form1 DFM file

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 565
  ClientWidth = 954
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ListView1: TListView
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 954
    Height = 565
    Align = alClient
    Columns = <
      item
        Width = 200
      end
      item
      end
      item
        Width = 200
      end
      item
      end
      item
        Width = 200
      end>
    Items.ItemData = {
      052F0000000100000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF03000000FFFFFFFF000000
      0000001890633600B8351F3D0000391F3DFFFFFFFFFFFF}
    RowSelect = True
    SmallImages = PngImageList1
    TabOrder = 0
    ViewStyle = vsReport
    OnCustomDrawSubItem = ListView1CustomDrawSubItem
  end
  object PngImageList1: TPngImageList
    PngImages = <
      item
        Background = clWindow
        Name = 'cross'
        PngImage.Data = {
          89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000100000001008060000001FF3FF
          610000001974455874536F6674776172650041646F626520496D616765526561
          647971C9653C000001CB4944415478DAAD933F4842411CC7BF8719D890363455
          342946E349D1D09F2DA7245C8AA2A1A11A1A9C8CA0A684701197201A45A8A6A0
          E951434343448A43E8524BA20922096543F6ECF5BB7BA73CCCCD1E1CC7BDDFF7
          FBB97BBFEF3B661806BA79D8BF004E1903A3850DF0D314A1B1D700345D897A3A
          D4C4B6CBE4B502A4606967879F45A369212480A600B2B6180AF18B785CD608A0
          B5004926F6476A251CE6B95C0E1E8F07E7B19814AA4344E6D7D779B95C86CBE5
          C24D32296ABED526206102FC448D04363779269381D7EBC555222184980C0478
          A95482D3E9C4E3F5759A99606DCD0A10DFA42BC85C30C89F9F9EA4A156ABA158
          28C0E170E0239F9766FA244D6CF907F04DA3A120236E377FAB54E4F96D361BDE
          2B1569A6666A76D17D2BE050A5D0AB1AC6046070903774BD15D76BB59A365463
          EBB4161BEEB603ECCA3C3E30C03B659E55906F15633B4046356D31DF9241CC1D
          DEC9185B800315E38245784942D56D71DC487B4DC4B8DF048C12608A4E3044C2
          0D129E90A048E67BF5234D76A8DD51EDA509608C0D93AECF07CC8C035B39E0E8
          814E4BEFBE68FC88FE4E00B363C07616384E99B54FF2169A807EB38732089869
          8ADF42CE867915E495E8517591789DBCEF5DDFC65FB962FBE11CAE7AA4000000
          0049454E44AE426082}
      end>
    Left = 248
    Top = 112
    Bitmap = {}
  end
end
```

PNGImageList: https://github.com/TurboPack/PNGComponents

Comment: I was about to test your problem, when I found out that your code has nothing to do with the `OnCustomDrawSubItem()` event. How exactly are you calling this your code `DrawPicOnListViewSubItem()`? What is `drBounds`, from where does its value come. In short, please provide a full code example, including relevant parts of the `.dfm` in order to create a proper test.

Comment: You are right. Full example provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main error in your code was that you did not draw the background ( `clHighLight` color ) for the selected row and for the subitem with the image.

In addition I removed the whole `DrawPicOnListViewSubItem()` procedure as I was able to reduce it to just a few lines. I think there was some trial code.

The `ListView1CustomDrawSubItem()` procedure is now as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1CustomDrawSubItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; SubItem: Integer; State: TCustomDrawState;
  var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  R: TRect;
  C: TCanvas;
begin
  ListView_GetSubItemRect(Sender.Handle, Item.Index, SubItem, LVIR_BOUNDS, @R);

  C := Sender.Canvas;

  if cdsSelected in State then
  begin
    C.Brush.Color := clHighLight;
    C.FillRect(R);
  end;

  if SubItem = 1 then
  begin
    ImageList_Draw(PngImageList1.Handle, 0, C.Handle, R.Left+(R.Width-PngImageList1.Width) div 2, R.Top, ILD_TRANSPARENT);
    DefaultDraw := False;
  end;

end;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works very well with my basic example, but it has some problems with OwnerData which is how I'm actually using the LV in the main application. Edited the question and code.

Comment: @hikari Please do not change your question, once you have got answers. Post a new question if your actual issue differs so much from your original question. What you are now asking for requires using `StyleServices` and is a different matter. Please revert your question to what it was when I answered.

Comment: Thank you! @hikari I post the following URL in case you haven't seen [this article](https://theroadtodelphi.com/2017/03/09/tlistview-ownerdraw-compat-with-windows-ui-vcl-styles/) regarding using `StyleServices` for an `OwnerDraw` listview. I'm currently working my way through it (as time allows) and may be able to answer questions about it in the future.

Comment: Thank you, I used to follow that blog as well, that demo has very useful code to implement what I need, with some adjustments I was able to adapt it to my app.